# Is there boilerplate or library out there for using Next.js API routes for Hasura Event and Action handling?

Tags: next.js, nestjs, hasura

I'm getting a Hasura project off the ground and seeing as the frontend of the app will be using Next.js I plan on also using API routes for handling Hasura [event triggers](https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/event-triggers/index.html) and [actions](https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/actions/index.html).

I came across this very nice lib for NestJS called [@golevelup/nestjs-hasura](https://github.com/golevelup/nestjs/tree/master/packages/hasura) that gives you a headstart in handling Hasura events, amongst other things making your API the source of truth when creating event triggers.

Does anyone know of a similar library or boilerplate that can give me a headstart in bootstrapping something sensible and semi-battletested?

Comment: After watching this video by the @golevelup/nestjs-hasura dev I'm tempted to give NestJS a go, but I feel like it's going to be a total rabbit hole and I'm keen to just get started using Next.js API routes. Would be stoked to hear if anyone has any suggestions.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wwCByO2la2I

Comment: I'm using Hasura for the first time on a project.  I'm using it with Apollo and Next.  I haven't got to using Hasura event triggers and actions yet I'd like to know this too!  I found this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WECxgivnwio

Comment: @oldo.nicho I'm the author of the NestJS integration, appreciate the praise! I'm not as familiar with NextJS but without having a Dependency Injection system that allows for decorators/method discovery I think it would be more challenging to recreate the functionality for that ecosystem. Feel free to reach out if you do have questions about the NestJS plugin